# Method of matched asymptotics for functions given by integrals

Tags: asymptotics, approximation-theory, perturbation-theory

This is more of a generic question. [Method of matched asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_matched_asymptotic_expansions) is a well-established method to approximate a function that is a solution of a given differential equation. 
However, what about the functions given by some *integral representation* $I(x)$ defined for $x\in(0,\infty)$, for which one can obtain an asymptotic expansion for small $x$,

$$ I(x) \sim f_1(x) + f_2(x) + \ldots, ~~~ x \to 0, $$

as well as for large $x$

$$ I(x) \sim g_1(x) + g_2(x) + \ldots, ~~~ x \to \infty. $$

Knowing these $f_n$ and $g_n$  functions how does one construct an approximate function for $I(x)$
valid on whole domain $(0,\infty)$? How does one match these two expansions in some in-between region? 
Is there even a well-defined procedure?

As a simple example, let's consider a Bessel function $J_0(x)$. 
Let me suppose I know only an integral form of this function, e.g.

$$ J_0(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i x \sin t} dt, $$

and that I was able to compute the asymptotics from this

$$J_0(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{4} + \ldots, ~~{\rm as}~~ x \to 0, $$

and

$$J_0(x) =\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4} - x\right) + \ldots, 
~~{\rm as}~~ x \to \infty. $$

Just by looking at the plot (see attached), there should be a way to do the matching somehow! But how to proceed?
[image]

Comment: a Pade approximation seems aproppriate here. maybe something like ${(1+a x) \over (1+b x^{3/2})}$

Comment: The red and blue approximants in your plot seem to be ~ accurate on disjoint intervals that for all $\mathbb{R}$. I wouldn't see more than a coincidence here: it could very well have been that the two approximants are accurate on a small / large intersection as well or that a whole interval could have been left out.
If you want a quick and dirty fix, maybe try $J(x) \approx \alpha(x) f_0(x) + (1-\alpha(x))*f_\infty(x)$, where $\alpha$ is a well-calibrated shifted regularization of the Heaviside function.

Comment: tnx for the feedback! Yes, that is in fact what I have been doing so far, I closed my eyes and made up some transition function you call $\alpha(x)$. But I would have thought there is some optimal strategy or framework developed, based on variation principle or something, that would at least discriminate between different $\alpha(x)$ attempts. Especially given that I provide an integral representation of the functions valid on the whole domain.